# Where does android.support.multidex reside in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-multidex

Does anyone have any idea where to look for [android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html) in Xamarin? I am unable to find it anywhere (tried all support libraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this date (30.11.2015) it doesn't reside anywhere (Xamarin's bugzilla has this issue filled in).

Comment: is it still the case?

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov not sure try to look at xamarins bugzilla

Answer (score 0):

Please review this link "https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/"

For Windows, the path of the aar file may be in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support (multidex & multidex-instrumentation)

In my case, to extend the MultiDexApplication class, using VisualStudio 2015 and Xamarin, I needed to create a new project in the solution, as explained in the link. Later, it had access available in the Android project.

Comment: Include a link to the answer is not a good one. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendations!